# Distinguishing a string from a string representation

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Python 3.4

I am writing a validation function to check a user's input. In one case I'm trying to validate the user entered an integer between 0 and 99.

Everything comes in as a string, and so assuming we have a string representation of an integer, the obvious place to start is with something like:

```
isinstance(int(userinput), int)
```

But assuming there is no end to the ways a user can make a mistake, suppose he or she enters '2l' by accident. This is actually a string, not a string representation of an integer. The above `isinstance()` check on this results in:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2l'
```

I can't figure out how to account for this possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `try` and `except`, and you don't even need the `isinstance` check:

```
userinput = None
try:
    userinput = int(input("type a number"))
except ValueError:
    print ("invalid input")

if userinput is not None:
     # rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for an arbitrary syntax with regular expressions. For a sequence of digits:

```
import re

match = re.search('\d+', userinput)
if match:
    print int(match.group(0))
```